# How to get Twitter banner url using TweetInvi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, twitter, tweetinvi

I'm using the TweetInvi nuget package to retrieve information from the Twitter API.

I'm using V2 and it's working great for most of the user profile image but I can't see any way to get the user's Twitter banner url. Am I missing something or does this not exist in TweetInvi? The Twitter API does provide this so seems strange if TweetInvi doesn't.

```
var userClient = new TwitterClient(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, 
accessTokenSecret);

var userProfile = await userClient.UsersV2.GetUserByNameAsync(twitterHandle);
```

Comment: This is not currently available in the Twitter API v2 unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I wasn't sure if that was the case or I just couldn't find it. That's a shame as unless I'm mistaken Twitter haven't stopped giving that version.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from Andy Piper, it seems this functionality is not available in TweetInvi V2.